# Session Management in Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

How come I customize the session in Liferay?Sample codes are welcome as it will help more,I am pretty new to Liferay?
To be more specific, i'll explain what i've done. Using Custom JSPs Hooks , i have overridden the $PORTAL_ROOT_HOME/html/portlet/login login.jsp and created my own jsp page and also overridden the LoginAction class.My login.jsp page looks like:

```
<aui:form action="" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Username :</td>
                <td><input name="login" size=15 type="text" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password :</td>
                <td><input name="password" size=15 type="password" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <aui:button type="submit" value="sign-in"/>
</aui:form>
```

Now please tell upon clicking on the submit button , how can i get the login values in LoginAction.java and hence set the values to session. This is what i mean by customizing.

Comment: You should elaborate on what you mean by "customising" the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have copied the origonal login.jsp file from the start. By the looks of your codesnipsets you forgot to set the action to your loginAction. This can be done the following way:

```
<portlet:actionURL secure="<%= PropsValues.COMPANY_SECURITY_AUTH_REQUIRES_HTTPS || request.isSecure() %>" var="loginURL">
            <portlet:param name="saveLastPath" value="0" />
            <portlet:param name="struts_action" value="/login/login" />
            <portlet:param name="doActionAfterLogin" value="<%= portletName.equals(PortletKeys.FAST_LOGIN) ? Boolean.TRUE.toString() : Boolean.FALSE.toString() %>" />
        </portlet:actionURL>

<aui:form action="<%= loginURL %>" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Username :</td>
                <td><aui:input name="login" size=15 type="text" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password :</td>
                <td><aui:input name="password" size=15 type="password" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <aui:button type="submit" value="sign-in"/>
</aui:form>
```

**Please note that it is better to copy the orginal $PORTAL_ROOT_HOME/html/portlet/login/ login.jsp to your hook. Then make the modifications if any needed.**

Your Hook will break / remove allot of existing functionality if the provided snipset is all you have.

To receive the parameters from the action you can use Pauls answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Its working fine now !! But i'm not able to get the login values as per Paul answer. I'm getting empty values. Do I have to write any model class?

Comment: Paul gave to answer you need to use aui:input tag indeed :-) , they add the required namespace

Answer (score 1):

You can get login values with this code:

```
    String login = ParamUtil.getString(request, "login");
    String password = ParamUtil.getString(request, "password");
```

To set some values to session use this:

```
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("parm", "somevalue");
```

BR,
Paul

Comment: Paul thanks for the reply.how can i set the action in the form? that is what i need is, when i click the submit button it should redirect to LoginAction class.

Comment: You should use aui input:
   <aui:input name="password" type="password" value="<%= password %>" />
it will generate input with portlet namespace prefix and you will be able to get it from request.

Also check original login.jsp at /portal/portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/login/login.jsp